# AmCharts map. Show data after loading screen

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, amcharts, ammap

I have some amCharts(version 3) map with large amount of data(pins) in my app. I want it to load data without freezing the page. In which way can I implement this. I was trying proccessTimeout, setInterval, setTimeout. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 2):

amMaps 3 isn't optimized to handle large amounts of data. There are a couple of workarounds you can try to help with performance somewhat but it isn't a 100% fix and may hit a ceiling if the amount of data is very large.

One option is to create a multi-level drill down where you display a smaller subset of your data in the form of regional markers. When a user clicks on one of them, the underlying data points are shown, ex:

```
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "usa2Low",
    "images": [ {
      "svgPath": targetSVG,
      "label": "San Diego", //Clicking on the San Diego marker 
      "zoomLevel": 14,      //will reveal markers for Imperial Beach, El Cajon, etc
      "scale": 1,
      "title": "San Diego",
      "latitude": 32.715738,
      "longitude": -117.161084,
      "images": [ {
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "title": "Imperial Beach",
        "latitude": 32.586299,
        "longitude": -117.110481
      }, {
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "title": "El Cajon",
        "latitude": 32.802417,
        "longitude": -116.963539
      }, {
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "title": "University City",
        "latitude": 32.861268,
        "longitude": -117.210045
      }, {
        "svgPath": targetSVG,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "title": "Poway",
        "latitude": 32.969635,
        "longitude": -117.036324
      } ]
    } ]
```

Here's an example: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/map-marker-drill-down/

Another option is to show certain data points only on particular zoom level using `groupId` and `zoomLevel`, which minimizes the number of points that needs to be rendered initially until the users looks for more detail, similar to the previous example but not using nested structures:

```
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "images": [ {
      "groupId": "minZoom-2", //minZoom-2 group of images, visible at zoomLevel 5
      "svgPath": targetSVG,
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Vienna",
      "latitude": 48.2092,
      "longitude": 16.3728
    }, 
    // ... other images with group minZoom-2 omitted
    // ...
     {
      "groupId": "minZoom-2.5", //minZoom-2.5 group, visible at 
      "svgPath": targetSVG,
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Pyinmana",
      "latitude": 19.7378,
      "longitude": 96.2083
    }, 
    // ... etc

// create a zoom listener which will check current zoom level and will toggle
// corresponding image groups accordingly
map.addListener( "rendered", function() {
  revealMapImages();
  map.addListener( "zoomCompleted", revealMapImages );
} );

function revealMapImages( event ) {
  var zoomLevel = map.zoomLevel();
  if ( zoomLevel < 2 ) {
    map.hideGroup( "minZoom-2" );
    map.hideGroup( "minZoom-2.5" );
  } else if ( zoomLevel < 2.5 ) {
    map.showGroup( "minZoom-2" );
    map.hideGroup( "minZoom-2.5" );
  } else {
    map.showGroup( "minZoom-2" );
    map.showGroup( "minZoom-2.5" );
  }
}
```

Here's an example of this: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/show-groups-map-images-specific-zoom-level/